# RxLib and C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

I have a problem with installing rxlib into C++ Builder 6...
So my question is - how PROPERLY I need to install RxLib and where I can get this lib?
because I can't install archive which I got here - http://rxlib.ru/arh/Comp/rxlib.rar

Comment: does anybody know something about RxLIB?

Answer (score 0):

After opening the RAR file you'll have 3 folders BPL, LIB, Rx. In the Rx folder there is a text file named install.log, this is an complete installation from some installer. It installed to the CBuilder5 folder not for CBuilder6. There is a file named readmed6.txt which shows how to install into Delphi 6 so IMHO will not work as is for CBuilder 6.

Answer (score 0):

All is right now, i was found good archive which works great with 6 CBC.

Comment: I know it is a long time ago now, but by any chance can you remember where you got a the RxLib that works with Borland C++ Builder 6 ? I have an old app that I need to build with it.